# Can the WPF ListView/GridView display multiline items?

Tags: wpf, listview, layout

My application uses a ListView/GridView control to display data records that the user can select and edit. This is based on http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-using-the-listview-part-3-in-place-edit. Now I have a case where the number of columns is larger and there's a text description on every line that indicates what object the user is editing in the line.

To save horizontal space, can that text description for each item be displayed above the other columns, in a separate row, spannng multiple columns, but still be included in the item selection when an item is selected? While all other columns are editable when selected, that info text is only static and cannot be edited by the user.

Here is a screen mockup as I felt it is necessary to understand what I mean. The red rectangles are only for highlighting the area of interest, they are not displayed in the application. This is based on the screenshot of the above mentioned link and the application behaviour is otherwise exactly the same. I just want that additional row to be displayed in each item.

[image: Screen mockup]

**Edit 2:** Now as I think about what I've painted, it looks like the grouping from ListViews in Explorer. Those group headers are not included in the selection though, but as they are also unselectable and skipped in keyboard selection, that would be okay, too, I think. I'm just continuing my search in that direction to see what I can find.

Please ask in the comments if anything is unclear.

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1498418/wpf-gridview-gridviewcolumn-two-lines-per-row

Comment: @Blachshma Sorry no. The other question entirely remains in a single existing cell. I need to span multiple columns and the other controls must remain on the same vertical alignment below that text. I've created a screen mockup to better explain what I mean.